# Regex escape questionmark and double quotes

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

I have data with several occurrencies of the following string:

```
<a href="default.asp?itemID=987">
```

in which the itemID is always different. I am using C# and I want to get all those itemIDs with a Regular Expression.

At first I tried this

```
"<a href=\"default.asp?itemID=([0-9]*)\">"
```

But the questionmark is a reserved character. I considered using the @ operator to disable escaping of characters. But there are still some double quotes that really need escaping. So then I would go for

```
"<a href=\"default.asp\\?itemID=([0-9]*)\">"
```

which should be translated (as a string) to

```
<a href="default.asp\?itemID=([0-9]*)">
```

But the Regex.Match method gets no success. I tried the very same regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and it worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I want to get all those itemIDs with a Regular Expression." You shouldn't. Use HTMLAgilityPack instead. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: This never gets old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: After all these discussions people still continue parsing HTML with Regex..

Comment: Those guys are right, you know. You shouldn't parse HTML with Regex. That said, I see no reason why one shouldn't *both* suggest another alternative and try to help you out.

Comment: Wow, seems like i hit on a sensible nerve here.
But i am not parsing some random HTML where everything can occur. I just need to replace some links that have been created by a WYSIWYG editor and are stored in a database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`?` and `.` are special chars for a regex, but can't be escaped "as is" in a string litteral.
So if you put one `\`, it will be wrong for a string, and if you don't put `\\`, it will be taken as the "special char" of the regexp. So :

```
"@<a href=\"default\\.asp\\?itemID=([0-9]*)\">";
```

Comment: Leave out the @ and that is the solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

When using the @operator, you can regain double quotes with "".

You also need to escape certain special chars in the regex, in this case, the chars .\?

Try this:

```
@"<a href=""default\.asp\?itemID=([0-9]*)"">"
```

Comment: One less than supposed. Because \ is the escape char, to get an actual backslash, you need \\. `.` and `?` both have special meaning and thus also need to be escaped.

Comment: Still too many blackslashes at the ? mark. This is a @ string ya know. Oh, I'm pretty sure you need to write `\.` in .NET regex, though I could be mistaken.

Comment: So... in the middle of the string we're looking to **exactly** match \? right? How does that escape? to my mind (and that of my test), \ becomes \\ and ? becomes \? giving \\\? . Am I wrong?

Comment: OP says the text is `<a href="default.asp?itemID=987">`

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the dot '.' character with `\.`